# Persist One to One Relation with Postgres Sequence

Tags: postgresql, jpa

I'm playing arround with JavaEE in my free time since a few Months

I have 2 Tables in Postgres

Table person

```
create table person(id bigint primary key default nextval('person_id_seq'), persontype varchar(5), name varchar(50), ERP_id smallint);
```

Table address

```
create table address (customer_id bigint primary key NOT NULL references person(id), department varchar(50), street varchar(50), plz varchar(10), city varchar(50), country varchar(50));
```

Model person

```
    public class Person implements Serializable {

        @Id
        @SequenceGenerator(
                name="person_id_seq",
                sequenceName="person_id_seq",
                allocationSize=1,
                initialValue=1
        )
        @GeneratedValue(
                strategy=GenerationType.AUTO,
                generator="person_id_seq"
        )
        private Long            id;

        private char            personType;

        private String          name;

        private Long            erp_id;

        @OneToOne (cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REMOVE, CascadeType.REFRESH})
        @JoinColumn(name="id", insertable=false, updatable=false)
        private Address address;

[...]    

    @PrePersist
    public void initializeCustomerId(){
        this.address.setCustomerId(id);
        }
```

Model address

```
public class Address implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(
            strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="person_id")
    private Long    personId;
    private String  department;
    private String  street;
    private int     plz;
    private String  city;
    private String  country;
```

I've got this solution from https://blogs.oracle.com/WebLogicServer/entry/ejb3_mapping_of_one-to-one_rel

My Problem now... before I persist I need the id which will be generated by the Postgres-Sequence.

My Thought on this: in @PrePersist I could do an

```
select nextval('person_id_seq');
```

BUT What if there are more Clients who wants to save at the same time!!

So, how could I solve this Issue? Or am I completely wrong on this?

Thanks

Paddie

Comment: No idea what you're trying to achieve there. Want the "id" of the Address to be exactly the same as the "id" of the Person?

Comment: Yes, thats exactly what I want.

Comment: So change your classes to have the sequence on Address, and make Person.address the @Id field.

Comment: Hmm.. I don't get this. The id will be generated at persisting in the Database. So in my Eyes, If I change it like you say. I have the same Problem, only at  another place.

Comment: If you really have Person ids corresponding to Address ids (AND there cannot be any Person with Address etc - strange model IMHO but anyway, a Person can have multiple addresses, and an Address can have multiple people FWIW) then that is the way to do it. If you try to persist a Person, it will see that the Address is required, persist it (with the sequence id) THEN persist the Person. So no, there is not the same problem

Comment: Oh, OK, now I understand ;-). On my Test I only have an One To One relation. But now after I read your Post. I think i change my Layout and use it like you write ;-). I think, then, there should be no Problem. THANKS for your Help!